# Cannot resolve Angular 6 compiler.js error

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm so confused.  I have an app, that's been working fine for over a year.  It uses Angular 6.  Last night I was adding a simple feature to it, 1 method in a service and 1 method in a component - and suddenly now I'm getting an Angular error from compiler.js.

The error is:

```
compiler.js:10912 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

The line referenced in the Error:

```
throw syntaxError(dirType.name + " cannot be used as an entry component.");
```

This is an error in the actual Angular core code, not mine.

The weird part is, if I remove the code I added to my app that started triggering this error, the error is still there.  Besides - it's not even any of my code that is referenced in the error.

What gives?  How do I go about figuring this out?

Here is a screenshot of the actual error:

[image: Error Screenshot]

Examining the stacktrace, the only reference to my code I see is confusing as hell:

[image]

How am I supposed to debug this webpackified string?

Here is the full trace:

[image]

Comment: check the error stack in the console. This snippet from angular core would be called from somewhere in your code.

Comment: @NithinKumarBiliya Yea, I guess that's another weird thing - the stack references my code at the very beginning - but when I click it to inspect it, it's a webpackified string, if that makes sense

Comment: @NithinKumarBiliya I added a picture to highlight what I'm talking about to my initial question

Comment: please attach the stack trace as well

Comment: @NithinKumarBiliya added

Comment: Here is a theory: you did not added the file package-lock.json to your source control, now when you restarted development on this project you did npm install on a clean workspace, then you got versions of all your dev tool and dependences that are different from what you were using the last time you worked on this project.

Comment: Or maybe you're running it with the global cli, which is using more recent versions of Angular's packages?

Comment: make sure you are building by using "npm run ng build" instead of simply "ng build", that way you build with the specific version of angular/cli that this project requires instead of some random version that you may have installed globally.

Comment: OK, I'll try that - I've been using the angular starter kit, and using `npm start` when developing.